# How can I modify a variable and it's corresponding dimension in a netcdf

Tags: matlab, netcdf, nco

I am running an idealized experiment with a atmospheric model with output in the format of netcdf. But the netcdf file header does not describe the variable and and dimension clearly. for example :

```
netcdf qc3d {
dimensions:
    Time = UNLIMITED ; // (1453 currently)
    bottom_top = 45 ;
    south_north = 32 ;
    west_east = 12288 ;
variables:
    float Time(Time) ;
        Time:axis = "Time" ;
        Time:long_name = "Time" ;
        Time:standard_name = "Time" ;
        Time:units = "minutes since 1900-01-01 " ;
    double zc(bottom_top) ;
        zc:axis = "Z" ;
        zc:long_name = "vertical height of model layers, MSL" ;
        zc:standard_name = "altitude" ;
        zc:units = "m" ;
        zc:positive = "up" ;
    double yc(south_north) ;
        yc:axis = "Y" ;
        yc:long_name = "y-coordinate of grid cell centers in Cartesian system" ;
        yc:units = "m" ;
    double xc(west_east) ;
        xc:axis = "X" ;
        xc:long_name = "x-coordinate of grid cell centers in Cartesian system" ;
        xc:units = "m" ;
    float qc(Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) ;
        qc:long_name = "cloud water mixing ratio" ;
        qc:standard_name = "cloud_water_mixing" ;
        qc:units = "kg kg-1" ;
        qc:_FillValue = 9.96921e+36f ;
        qc:missing_value = 9.96921e+36f ;

// global attributes:
        :model_tag = "CSU VVM" ;
        :references = "http://kiwi.atmos.colostate.edu/pubs/joon-hee-tech_report.pdf" ;
        :contact = "jung@atmos.colostate.edu" ;
        :institution = "Colorado State University" ;
        :VVM_casename = "GATE_PHASE_III                                                                  " ;
}
```

there are 4 dimensions,  Time(Time), zc(bottom_top), yc(south_north), xc(west_east) and 5 variable in which first 4 variables should be the dimension of the fifth variable, so called qc. But it seems not. The dimension is just a series number index from 1 to 45, 32 ...whatever else.

I would like to calculate some variable which is the function of pressure. in the CDO the script is like this

```
cdo expr,"pottemp=temp*((100000/clev(temp))^0.287);"  ifile pottemp.nc
```

(this code is from [here](https://code.zmaw.de/boards/53/topics/3839))

but I just obtain a series of index like 1 ,2 ,3 ... not the real pressure  level when I use this function, clev(qv). 
So how can I rewrite the variable dimension like qc from 
`qc(Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) ;`
to
`qc(Time, zc, yc, xc) ;`
I think it's possible for me to finish this in matlab, but I just don't want to open this dataset because it's size is too large... so I am trying to find some tools like ncks or cdo, but still failed to do this.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With NCO try

```
ncap2 -s 'pottemp=temp*((100000/zc)^0.287)' in.nc out.nc
```

[ncap2 documentation](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncap2)

extending answer to cover additional question below:

first use ncap2 to explicitly set zc to the values in the ascii file:

```
ncap2 -s 'zc[$zc]={1.5,900,2500,3500}' in.nc out.nc
```

(assuming zc is size 4 dimension). then define pottemp based on that zc.

Comment: thank you!! 
I think this works. another problem is that "zc" is vertical height in the unit of meter, but  what I need is pressure level. Unfortunately, I don't have any nc file is this type of pressure level. what I have is a ascii file which describe the vertical index and its responding pressure level, height and density. 
is there any way to rewrite the ncfile variable from a list of an ascii file ?
thank you~~